# Why does this not work with an imaginary exponent?

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone please tell me why this exponentiation rule does not work when the exponent is imaginary?

The following seems to be true but is only true if $x$ is an integer.

$$e^{2\pi ix} = \left( e^{2\pi i} \right)^x = 1^x = 1$$